# Laravel 5 pagination : MethodNotAllowedHttpException error

Tags: pagination, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have problem with my pagination:

Controller code:

```
  $pagination = Orders::latest()->paginate(2);
  return view('orders.index',compact('pagination')
);
```

View code:

```
{!! str_replace('/?', '?', $pagination->render()) !!}
```

All data have been loaded on page, that is fine, also pagination is on bottom, but when click on page 2, I get the following error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 7717

Comment: Is your route a get route?

Comment: NO, post route..IS that a problem ?

Comment: Yes, because the link you are clicking will do a get request which is why you get the error.

Comment: IS there a way to fix that?

Comment: Sure, change the route to `GET` or fetch the data via f.e. an ajax `POST` request

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `Route::any` instead of `Route::post`.